Notepad++ can open folder in ubuntu 22.04, and sudo notepad-plus-plus cannot open notepad++
I install notepad++ on my ubuntu VM following this link https://www.fosslinux.com/69203/install-notepad-on-ubuntu.htm
then when I open notepad++ by
notepad-plus-plus

and select File > Open, I found my folder cannot be seen, e.g. under /tmp, under mnt/

and many error show in terminal, as follow:

$ notepad-plus-plus ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. Starting application.. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored.

and if I use command
sudo notepad-plus-plus

it throws many error and the notepad++ cannot be opened. the error is like following:

$ sudo notepad-plus-plus mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’:
Permission denied ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135 Installing
application.. Running hook
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/sommelier/hooks/pre-install' Starting
application.. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. ERROR: ld.so: object
'/snap/notepad-plus-plus/411/gnome-platform/$LIB/bindtextdomain.so'
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):
ignored. wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135

what should I do to open a file under /tmp in notepad++ in Ubuntu 22.04?

you are trying to run Npp in linux/gnome using wine?

should be yes, after I installed and run notepad++ the first time, I see a popup said some update of wine (not remember what the message is).

Notepad space plus space plus?

No, if use notepad space plus space plus, it returns "notepad: command not found
"
